# What is the simplest way to check if a variable matches a line somewhere within a file in BASH?

Tags: bash, if-statement, find

I need to check if a variable can be found somewhere within a file (matching the exact line from beginning to end), e.g.:

```
if [ "$find" is in file.txt ]
then
    echo "Found."
else
    echo "Not found."
fi
```

I have been using `grep -c '^$find$' > count.txt`, then `count="$(cat count.txt)"`, then checking if `$count` is greater than "0", but this method seems inefficient.

What is the simplest way to check if a variable is found, in its entirely, as a line somewhere within a file?

Answer (score 6):

Use `grep`:

```
grep -q "$find" file.txt && echo "Found." || echo "Not found."
```

If you want to match the entire line, use the `-x` option:

```
grep -xq "$find" file.txt && echo "Found." || echo "Not found."
```

Quoting `man grep`:

```
  -q, --quiet, --silent
          Quiet; do not write anything to standard output.   Exit  immedi-
          ately  with  zero status if any match is found, even if an error
          was detected.  Also see the -s or --no-messages option.

  -x, --line-regexp
          Select only those matches that exactly match the whole line.
```

---

The above can also be written as:

```
if grep -xq "$find" file.txt; then
    echo "Found."
else
    echo "Not found."
fi
```

Comment: You need anchors `^ and $` also to match entire line.

Comment: @anubhava For that `grep` provides `-x` option.

Comment: Yes `-x` is also fine to avoid anchors. +1

Comment: This works with one line, but what do I do if I need to place much code where `echo "Found."` is?